# How can I load a Docker image created from the .tar file of an original Docker image?

Tags: docker, tar, archive

I have a Docker image in .tar format. When I load it using `sudo docker load < image.tar`, it works fine.

I used `tar -xf image.tar` to un-archive the file. I then un-archived each layer file so I could edit some scripts and update some libraries manually. Once I was done with this, I used `tar -cf` on each layer and then the entire image.

When I load the modified image the same way I loaded the original, it does not work. I get this error:

`open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-742628246/image-edited/json: no such file or directory`

What could I have done wrong to cause this error and how can I properly load the modified .tar file into Docker?

P.S.: The problem appeared on Docker 20.10.12, running on Kali Linux 2021.4 inside VMWare Workstation Player.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is the issue, but layers are designed to be immutable. I suspect that you untaring the layers, changing them and re-taring them did not went unnoticed.

Comment: @Turing85 That is what I am doing to the layers. Is there a way to change the layers without causing this error?

Comment: Not sure. I would rather write a custom containerfile (or something else that is reproducible) instead of "hacking" an image this way.

Comment: Why don't you load the image then build a new one extending it with a `Dockerfile` from your local registry? You can then export the new image if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am modifying some image tarball and trying to load it back to docker daemon, and saw the same error. I tried this: `sha256sum` the `layer.tar` in each layer, and search the config json file(the other json file at the same level as `manifest.json`, with a long sha value as filename) for the original hash, replace with the new sha256 value, then this error disappears.

But then again, another error like `/var/lib/docker/tmp-xxxx/xxxxx cannot open file` appears, then I think nothing should/can be modified in the layer tar, as we cannot bypass docker checking the integrity of image in any easy way.

I am planning to adding another layer to the image using Google jib tool, where I copy some script to the container which does the modification I want, so that original layers keep intact.